# Thumbnail is not generated while uploading a video which is downloaded from the same server

Tags: php, video, file-upload, drupal-7, ffmpeg

I am using `drupal 7` video module and `ffmpeg` together to upload video on my site.
My problem:

1. Upload a video, everything works fine, thumbnail is generated and video is uploaded successfully
2. Now download the above uploaded video.
3. Now Try to upload the same video, on same drupal site.

Thumbnail is not generating and also I am not able to play the newly uploaded video.
In all other cases video upload is working fine, I am able to upload same video again and again with no fuss,but when I try to upload the downloaded video , everything goes wrong even if I change the file name after downloading the video and uploading again.

Please let me know if I am not clear, will try to explain more.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at the ffmpeg log/console output when you try to re-upload a previously downloaded file. There could be something wrong while the file is re-processed.

If you need more help please provide the output of the ffmpeg console of the video and a sample file that is not working with encoding/processing settings.